# Cannot release app in Test flight for testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

i am using Realm database in my application and when i try to release the app in Test flight for testing, some error is occurring always as your application is converted into invalid binary, then i got an mail from apple support, which i had included below

Mail from Apple:

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
"Cityguide CPH". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
corrected:

INVALID BUNDLE STRUCTURE - The binary file
'Maps.app/Realm.framework/Realm' is not permitted. Your app can't
contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the
CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming
Guide for information on the iOS app bundle structure.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
corrected binary.

please advice how to clear this error and release my app in TestFlight.. thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that a Realm.framework file was accidentally added to the root directory of the project. Please check the list of files in the project. Or if you use package manager (like CocoaPods or Carthage) to setup Realm, updating it to the latest version may resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks a lot. i solved it by removing the framework from copy bundle resources